# How is dynamically allocated space freed when a program is interrupted using Ctrl-C?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled and run, and is interrupted while in execution by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, how is the memory allocated to `p` freed? What is the role of the Operating System here? And how is it different from that in case Of C++, done using the `new` operator?

Comment: The operating system reclaims everything when a process terminates, no matter how it terminates.

Comment: What's so special about `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: How does the OS reclaim the memory?? More specifically, what component of the OS is responsible for doing that??

Comment: The OS does it however it wants, and the OS' memory manager is responsible. As it is after your program's execution, not only can you not manipulate it (or should not), you shouldn't even need to worry about it. Your code is gone by that point (unless you're writing a debugger).

Comment: Not to diminish the coding task, but a virtual memory enabled operating system only allocates virtual memory for a process.  Turning virtual memory into no memory is very easy, just delete the page mapping tables.  Poof, gone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a process terminates, the operating system reclaims all the memory that the process was using.

The reason why people make a big deal out of memory leaks even when the OS reclaims the memory your app was using when it terminates is that usually non-trivial applications will run for a long time slowly gobbling up all the memory on the system. It's less of a problem for very short-lifetime programs. (But you can never tell when a one-liner will become a huge program, so don't have any memory leaks even in small programs.)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how the OS reclaims the memory that the process was using?? Any specific process that does this for the OS??

Comment: @4sh1sh each program gets its own stack and free store (heap). When a program calls `new` / `delete`, it starts using up its free store. When a program exits, the OS takes back all that memory, including the stack and everything else. It doesn't care what specific blocks of memory in the free store were being used for (e.g. what had been `new`d or `delete`d, etc). It just takes back the entire thing.

Comment: Is there any specific process in the OS, specifically UNIX, that does this for the OS??

Comment: On Windows, at least, every process has its own virtual address space, and the OS knows how that virtual memory maps to physical memory. All dynamic allocations use virtual memory internally. When a process terminates, the OS knows what virtual memory has been assigned to the process and how much of it is still in use, so it knows which physical memory needs to be reclaimed.

Answer (score 4):

By the way (in addition to Seth Carnegie said):

Using the routines in `<signal.h>` you can catch the `SIGINT` signal (interrupt) to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in any way, for example to clean up any important resources, not only the memory (like closing files, thus avoiding the loss of any buffered and not-yet-written content, or closing network connections gently).

Answer (score 0):

The full explanation of `_exit` is here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html

The same things happen when a process terminates as a result of a fatal signal.

Answer (score 0):

the memory is actually not "free()"d at all.

memory acquired by the operating system is page size (4kbytes of memory usually). whenever a process runs out of memory it acquires additional pages, these are the space malloc() actually uses. when a process terminates all pages are returned to the operating system making calling free actually unnecessary. if your programme is a server or similar every piece of memory that is never freed will only be returned when the programme is actually killed - making it every more memory hungry.