# How prevent memory leak, when killed with tast manager

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is dynamically allocated space freed when a program is interrupted using Ctrl-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277477/how-is-dynamically-allocated-space-freed-when-a-program-is-interrupted-using-ctr)

my application uses pointers, so memory needs to be allocated.

What happen if you kill my application with Task Manager? 
Will windows free the allocated memory?

*My destructors are not called, so my application can't clean up :(*

**Is there a solution?**

Comment: Yes, Windows reclaims the memory once your process ends.

Answer (score 2):

When a process is killed (or ends in any other way), operating system reclaims the memory used by the process, so there will be no memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory within your process is tied to the process itself. If the process is stopped with task manager then all of the memory it allocated will be freed.

Memory leaks only occur while programs are running.