# Destructor calling when program is interrupted

Tags: c++

I'm creating a socket connection in my program using a class `Socket` I've made. The program runs in an infinite loop and to exit it I use ctrl-c. Now when I close the program, My destructor is not being called (The memory is freed as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277477/how-is-dynamically-allocated-space-freed-when-a-program-is-interrupted-using-ctr) but the socket is not freed upon interrupting the program). Is there a way to call the destructor exiting such a program?

The socket class definition:

```
class Socket
{
        private:
                int m_sock;
                sockaddr_in m_addr;
        public:
                Socket();
                virtual ~Socket();

                // Server initialization
                bool create();
                bool bind ( const int port );
                bool listen() const;
                bool accept ( Socket& ) const;

                // Client initialization
                bool connect ( const std::string host, const int port );

                // Data Transimission
                bool send ( const std::string ) const;
                int recv ( std::string& ) const;

                void set_non_blocking ( const bool );

                bool is_valid() const { return m_sock != -1; }
};
```

Destructor definition:

```
Socket::~Socket(){
      close(m_sock);
}
```

main function:

```
        try {
                // Create the socket
                ServerSocket server ( 15000 );
                std::cout << "Server running on 0.0.0.0:15000" << std::endl;
                std::string res;
                while(true) {
                        ServerSocket new_sock;
                        server.accept ( new_sock );
                        try {
                                while(true) {
                                        std::string data;
                                        new_sock >> data;
                                        res = process_query(data, kv_map, zset_map);
                                        new_sock << res;
                                }
                        }
                  catch(SocketException&) {}
                }
        }
        catch ( SocketException& e ){
                std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\nExiting.\n";
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: Might be handy to see the code

Comment: the standard answer to this kind of question is to use boost::asio for sockets and signal (ctrl-c) detection. It takes care of all of the complication for you.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm not using any external libraries. I'm implementing it using C++ I write.

Comment: @EdHeal I've added the code

Comment: @ayushgp: It is _impossible_ in to write code that uses sockets in C++ without external libraries, so your statement must be false. (Presumably you're using the facilities provided by libc and described by POSIX.)

Comment: The answers on the question you linked us to .... well, answer your question. Did you read them all? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7277610/560648

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet my bad. Should have read all the answers. BTW the external libraries I was talking about were those that dont ship with the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a signal handler for SIGINT ( signal generated when you click CTRL-C). 
Using C++ standard lib you can write:

```
void close_connection(int signal)
{
  delete socket; // invoke destructor
  socket.close(); // Alternative, you can add a close method to your socket class
}

// Install a signal handler
std::signal(SIGINT, close_connection);
```

You can find more information how to manage signal in C++ here 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

Comment: Is there a way to implement this in my program? The handler function signature must be equivalent to `handler(int)`. I need to pass it the `ServerSocket` object as I don't want to make it global.

Comment: what about `std::bind`?  you could create a function which takes 2 arguments and bind it to the socket object you want to free when the SIGINT has been received. In this way you avoid the global.